# $x^{\log_b{a}}=2$ ; find $x$.

Tags: logarithms, contest-math

I was solving one problem in which I had to find the value of $x$ and at the last step my result came out to be $x^{\log_b{a}}=2$ but I was not able to get to the correct answer after this. Here's what I did:

$$\begin{align}
&x^{\log_b{a}}=2\\
\Rightarrow\; & \log_b{a}\cdot\log_b{x}=\log_b{2} \rightarrow \text{Taking log to the base }b\text{ on both side}\\
\Rightarrow\; & \log_b{x}=\frac{\log_b{2}}{\log_b{a}}\\
\Rightarrow\; & \log_b{x}= \log_a{2}
\end{align}$$
But as you see I was not able to proceed ahead and I tried other ways to get to the solution but I was not able to.

The correct answer that has been provided is $x=2^{\log_a{b}}$. Can someone please help me as to how to get to this form of the answer?

Comment: Note the edits I made to your question. In general, it is better to use double dollar signs to format multiline equations. The `\begin{align}\end{align}` environment helps to further typeset it so it looks nicer. I advise you review all my edits to see how they improve the post :)

Comment: Also, instead of writing `$log$` for logarithms, which ends up looking like $log$ which looks like $l$, multiplied by $o$ multiplied by $g$, write `$\log$` which typesets it as $\log$. Same for $sin,cos,arctan$ and so on which are all better as $\sin,\cos,\arctan$. And one final thing, use `$\cdot$` for the multiplication sign instead of a period. $a\cdot b$ looks much nicer than $a.b$.

Comment: @5xum : Thanks! I will take care of these things from the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the reals, if $\beta > 0$, the solution to the equation $$x^{\alpha} = \beta$$ is $x=\beta^\frac{1}{\alpha}$ which is also sometimes written as $x=\sqrt[\alpha]{\beta}$.

Note that this is the same solution as the provided answer, because in your case, $\beta=2$ and $\alpha=\log_b a$, which means

$$x=2^{\frac{1}{\log_b a}} = 2^{\log_a b}$$

the last equality being true because, in general,
$$\frac{1}{\log_b(a)} = \frac{1}{\frac{\ln a}{\ln b}} = \frac{\ln b}{\ln a} = \log_a(b)$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $\rm\log$ w.r.t. $\rm \, base\,2$ so that $$\rm\log_ba \log_2x=1\implies \log_2x=\frac 1{\log_ba}=\log_ab\implies x=2^{\log_ba}$$

The first implication assumes $\rm a\ne 1$.

Comment: $a\ne 1$ follows from $x^{\log_b a} = 2$ as $a= 1$ implies $ 1 = x^0 = \ne 2$

Comment: @martini: yes, I just wanted to emphasize and justify the division by $\log_ba$. :)